# WPF DataGrid Automatically selecting checkbox bug?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and loading some data of custom type. Also have a `Checkbox column`. When checkbox is checked current row data is taken by following code. For first checkbox it's fine.

Then i check another checkbox and it gets checked but when i scroll through data i see some other rows **checkbox checked automatically** ! And when again i go up the check box that i selected first time is now unchecked and some other is selected automatically !

**The code i am using for checked Event.**

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedOrder = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem as AutoOrderClass;
    if (selectedOrder != null)
    {
        var order = SelectedOrdersList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VendorName == selectedOrder.VendorName);
        if (order == null)
        {
            OrdersCount++;
            TotalOrders.Text = "Total Orders : " + OrdersCount;
        }

        SelectedOrdersList.Add(selectedOrder);
    }
}
```

**And this is Xaml**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DataGridContainerPanel}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="CheckBoxColumn" Header="Select">
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style>
                    <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="CheckBox_Checked"/>
                    <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Description}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VendorName" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Binding="{Binding VendorName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity In Hand" Width="100" Binding="{Binding StockQuantity}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order QTY" Width="70" Binding="{Binding OrderQuantity,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="80" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Price" Width="70" Binding="{Binding TotalPrice,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

And here is the picture of **what's happening** !
**First Pic:** all fine only first row selected

**Second Pic :** Select another BUT See third column was auto checked When i scroll down i see some others are also got checked

**3rd Pic :** now i scroll up and see the first check box was auto unchecked how ?
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try setting [EnableRowVirtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization?view=netframework-4.8) property of Datagrid to false

Comment: @SajithSageer ahahah it worked you are genius man Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@SajithSageer** said setting `EnableRowVirtualization= false` for `DataGrid` resolves this issue.

Comment: This is not optimal solution if you have a lot of records, in that case create a view model for each row of the datagrid and bind the checkbox is checked property with viewmodel's boolean property.